# Do int return the memory location/address?

Tags: c, memory

There is no code for this question at all..Just a simple question... As strings return their memory location\address but do int do the same or there is something else going on?  ||  (pardon me if there's any mistake in this question I am just a beginner in programming and I just know the basic concepts of it.)||

Comment: Do you mean a function that has return type `int`, like `int add () {...}` or do you just mean a normal variable like `int a = 5;`? (which is treated as an immediate value, unlike an array where array/pointer conversion applies on access)

Comment: A string is nothing more than **an array of char** in which one of the elements is `'\0'`. An **array of int** (eg: `int a[10];`) when used other than with `&` or `sizeof` likewise "returns their memory location" (eg: `memmove(a+1, a, sizeof *a);` is the same as `a[1] = a[0];`).

Comment: Strings in C are `char` arrays which "decay" to a pointer in certain cases, like all C arrays do. For an answer more specific than that, it would help if you provided some code showing the context of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return a string, you return a pointer to a char.

- When you return a pointer to a char (address of a char), a pointer (an address) is returned.

  ```c
  char *x; ... return x;
  ```
- When you return a pointer to an int (address of an int), a pointer (an address) is returned.

  ```c
  int *x; ... return x;
  ```
- When you return an int, an int is returned.

  ```c
  int x; ... return x;
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ikegami this answer really helped me. I understood it. Appreciated!